# Last 30 days in 'Date' Data Type Column in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a column called `Start_Date` which is of the data type `Date`. For example `2/27/2016`. How can I find out the last 30 days from the current date for the column `Start Date`?

```
WHERE Start_Date=CURRENT_DATE-30
```

The above where clause would only give me the value for just `3/13/2019`.

I need the values for all the dates between `current_date` and `3/13/2019` for column `Start Date`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
WHERE Start_Date between CURRENT_DATE-30 and CURRENT_DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `start_date` is never in the future, then you can just use inequality:

```
WHERE Start_Date >= CURRENT_DATE - 30
```

I don't recommend using `BETWEEN` with dates -- because the time component (if any) can cause confusion.  So, if you have future dates and want to filter those out:

```
WHERE Start_Date >= CURRENT_DATE - 30 AND
      Start_Date <= CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: You mean the below syntax is not recommended in Teradata?.
WHERE Start_Date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 30 AND CURRENT_DATE;

Comment: @Kharthigeyan . . . In one sense, the syntax is fine if you know that `start_date` is really just a date.  However, that can sometimes be tricky.  Aaron Bertrand has written a blog about this subject (https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Although written for SQL Server, most of the ideas apply regardless of database.

Comment: You could allways cast it as a date - `where cast(start_date as date) >= current_date`. Although I think teradata will do an implicit cast here.

Comment: @Andrew . . . I emphasize that the logic is fine.  The point is "defensive programming".  I almost never use `between` with date/time types at all, to prevent errors in general.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the blog link

Comment: It's important to note though that if this Teradata table is partitioned on that date that your `>=` may expand that partition elimination causing unnecessary I/O. If it IS partitioned, than BETWEEN or a combination of `>=` and `<=` is recommended.